# What is the purpose of the /etc/apt/preferences.d directory in Ubuntu?

Tags: apt

When I put some apt config file into `/etc/apt/preferences.d` of my Ubuntu 20 LTS desktop, it is ignored (cannot be seen in the output of `apt-config dump`).
When I instead put the same `*.conf` file into the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` directory, it is honored (can be seen in the output of `apt-config dump`).

So what is the purpose of the `/etc/apt/preferences.d` directory in Ubuntu ?

Comment: if not ... https://difyel.com/linux/etc/apt/preferences/

Comment: @user535733, not before asking - but now I did: Seems `preferences.d` is for `*.pref` files that contain preferences for packages, but preferences for `apt-config` must go into `apt.conf.d/*.conf`. Maybe the word "preferences" was misleading for me. If this is the correct answer, please write it as an answer and I would accept it.

Comment: OK, did not reach you, so writing this as my own answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to `man apt_preferences`, the directory `/etc/apt/preferences.d` is for `*.pref` files that contain preferences for packages, but preferences for `apt-config` must go into `apt.conf.d/*.conf`.

`apt-config` ignores wrong `*.conf` files in `/etc/apt/preferences.d`, but `apt-get install` warns with
`Ignoring file 'somefile.conf' in directory '/etc/apt/preferences.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension`.

Comment: Glad to see you figured it out.